# How common or acceptable was it for a female yeoman or peasant in 14th century Germany to move around alone?

Tags: middle-ages

My query is specifically about an early teenage yeoman's daughter in what is modern day Saxony-Anhalt region in Germany. My period is the turn of the 14th Century.

From my reading in medieval histories it's clear that it could be dangerous for anyone, male or female to travel long distances alone (especially in certain areas). My curiosity is specifically about local travel for women, ie moving about for foraging, going to market in a nearby town, visiting in a nearby village etc. Even if this was considered unadvisable or unconventional, I'm interested in whether it might still have been done.

Comment: [Please don't repost closed questions](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/60437/40279); instead, edit your original post, and it'll go into the re-open queue.

Comment: This question is clearer and more specific than the earlier closed question; easier to proceed with this question than to go back and edit the prior question.  I know that BBC history has written some articles on the prevalence of travel for commoners _in England_, I'm unaware of any sources that deal with Germany.  Might be useful to consult pilgrimage records.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How common or acceptable was it for a female yeoman or peasant in 14th century northern Europe to move around alone?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/60437/how-common-or-acceptable-was-it-for-a-female-yeoman-or-peasant-in-14th-century-n)

Comment: I've put in a Delete vote on the other question so we can proceed with this one only taking into account MarkCWallace's comment; @jwenting